# InDesign links don't look good

Tags: adobe-indesign, image-quality

I've moved to a new computer (mac to mac) and from a pervious version of InDesign. The file I've opened from the previous version opens fine.

But, even if the links are all in the same directory, they show up as blurry and pixelated.

InDesign does not show that they are missing, in the links panel, it shows as if they are fine.

But if I relink a file manually (relink -> find the directory in the finder -> select the file (using the same file, from the same place that InDesign shows in the link panel) then the file shows up well - meaning it shows up with good resolution, not pixelated.

The problem is that I have 200 files linked to the InDesing file so I can't be manually relinking each one, what's the solution to this?

Comment: Make a backup of the project. Try renaming the "Links" folder to something else. Open the indd and all the links will be missing. Save and close. Change the name of the folder with images back to "Links"and open the indd again.

Answer (score 0):

In the links aren't *broken* then this is most likely just a display setting in InDesign.

Check the **Display Settings**...

`View > Display Performance` - Check that it's on `High Quality`

If that doesn't help, select an image and choose `Object > Display Performance` - Check that it's on `High Quality`

---

There are also settings in the **InDesign Preferences > Display Settings** to set these options how you'd prefer.

By *default* I believe a fresh install of INDD will use `Typical Display` for these settings. This can cause previews to look like lower quality images than they really are. I set mine to `High Quality Display` and only run into (slowdown) issues when there are a great many images INDD must preview.

Comment: It is not the display perfromance, i've checked it already, sorry i didn't mention this.

Comment: the display performance is set to high quality, within the same indesign document, as mentioned, the files that i manually relink display correctly, high quality, the ones that should display correctly also tho don't, they are neither missing (red circle !) nor outdated (yellow triangle !), further more the display panel says there's 0 missing links

Comment: @user180896 Well, I'm lost. If all links are reported as up to date and present, and the Display Performance is set.. I don't know of anything else that would cause this. I'd **try** using Save as with a new file name, then close and reopen the saved file. The transition to a new app version may have caused a gremlin or something.

Comment: What file types are you linking? I only ask because I remember working on an older project with various .EPS files linked, and ID had issues previewing them within the document. Also, have you tried exporting a high-quality PDF from ID? Does the resulting files display the same?